# All Form Post with multipart/form-data returning 404 even when route exists

Tags: php, html, laravel, upload, laravel-5.7

I have a form in my Laravel 5.7 application to allow a user to upload a CSV file for importing data. It has been working for a few weeks. However, suddenly it started returning 404 errors for all POST requests where the form had `multipart/form-data` as its `enctype`. The strange thing is that when I change it to `URLEncoded`* there is no 404.

I have tried several things.

1. Changing the route name.
2. Checking `php artisan route:list` output to verify routes exist.
3. Accessing the route via GET method, and I get method not allowed exception.
4. Clearing the cache.

**Blade Form**

```php
<form action="/import/createParts/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="csv_upload_file">Select the File</label>
        <input type="file" name="csv_upload_file">
    </div>

    @csrf
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::prefix('import')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/createParts', 'Import\CreatePartsController@index');
    Route::post('/createParts/upload', 'Import\CreatePartsController@upload');
});
```

Ideally, this should pass the form over to the function, and another process happens.

Comment: have you tried `action={{ url('/import/createParts/upload') }}` in your form action?

Comment: Are there other routes besides the 2 in your question that have `/createParts` in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set a name for your route, it's useful.

**Routes**

```php
Route::prefix('import')->group(function () {
    Route::post('createparts/upload', 'Import\CreatePartsController@upload')
        ->name('import.createparts.upload');
});
```

**Blade**

```php
<form method="post" action="{{ route('import.createparts.upload') }}" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="csv_upload_file">Select the File</label>
        <input type="file" name="csv_upload_file">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: his route clearly states its a `POST` route. Why add `@method('put')`?

Answer (score 0):

Named route concept is much more easy way handling the routes.

In `web.php`

```
Route::post('import/createParts/upload', 'Import\CreatePartsController@upload')
    ->name('createparts.upload');
```

In `blade`

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('createparts.upload') }}" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf

   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="csv_upload_file">Select the File</label>
     <input type="file" name="csv_upload_file">
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```